# Problems with mpirun (openmpi)

Tags: drivers, cluster, mpi

I have locally installed two openmpi versions on my cluster:

- openmpi-1.8.1 : when I run mpirun under this version, it gives me an error:

  ```
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  librdmacm: Fatal: unable to open RDMA device
  ```
- openmpi-2.0.0 : when I run mpirun under this version, it tells me:

  ```
  mca_base_component_repository_open: shmem "/opt/openmpi-1.8.1/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_posix" uses an MCA interface that is not recognized (component MCA v2.0.0 != supported MCA v2.1.0) -- ignored

  It looks like opal_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
  likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
  fail during opal_init; some of which are due to configuration or
  environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
  here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
  Open MPI developer):
    opal_shmem_base_select failed
    --> Returned value -1 instead of OPAL_SUCCESS
  ```

Both versions are installed locally in /opt and loaded as modules. It seems openmpi-2.0.0 still uses dependencies of openmpi-1.8.1, which I don't understand.

I will appreciate any diagnostics and/or hints to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not install them at the same place their libraries are conflicting with each other. openmpi 2.0.0 uses MCA interface 2.1.0, openmpi 1.8.1 uses MCA interface 2.0.0. So you should install the libraries in a separate places

Comment: Please explain how to do that or your answer might be deleted.